# Windows 7 - Searching within file names

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, search

Windows 7 Home Premium
64 Bit

I have download an icon set of over 1,000 icons, and all of the files start with "appbar", for example: "appbar.email." In order to find what I'm looking for I need scroll through over 1,000 files to find the right one. Upon trying the windows search bar in explorer, with the icon folder open, I didn't get the expected results. I typed "mail" and it didn't give any results. I also tried "*mail", which didn't give any results. Thinking it was looking for the entire file name, I tried "appbar.mail", and that also didn't show the "appbar.mail" file (no results). How can I search for parts of file names using the search bar in the explorer folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this page](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-customize-windows-7s-search-settings.html) to see if your search settings are properly configured.

The Windows 7 search should work as "bring me back any file that contains the phrase I type in, or has that phrase in the filename". But it seems as if in your case it doesn't.

You can also try adding *ext: **file-extension*** for the specific file-extension. In this case, I'm assuming it's '.ico'.

Comment: Checking the "Don't use the index when searching in the file folders for system files" box fixed the issue. Thanks.